# Do (Cross-compile) platform files require an include guard?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, toolchain, include-guards

I'm writing a Cross-compiling Toolchain file for VxWorks. Since it's an unknown system to cmake a also have write platform files (those in `../Modules/Platform`).

Beside my **toolchain** file I have written these platform files so far:

- **VxWorks.cmake** (VxWorks OS settings)
- **VxWorks-gcc.cmake** (WindRiver (Gnu) compiler settings)
- **VxWorks-gcc-*[CPU]*.cmake** (CPU specific settings,  is the processor as specified in the toolchain file)

Everything works fine with my files at the moment.

But some of the default platform files contain a include guard / *include blocker* like this one:

```
if(__WINDOWS_GNU)
  return()
endif()
set(__WINDOWS_GNU 1)
```

*(from: `Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake`)*

So i'm wondering: Do I have to insert such a guard too? And when it's a good idea to insert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake modules can include each other, so it can lead to [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). 
If you are lucky, you've got double work for setting some variables, but if
you will need some complex stuff, things may get worse.

Example:

*FindB.cmake*

```
find_package(A)
```

*FindA.cmake*

```
find_package(B)
```

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

find_package(A) # include FindA.cmake, which include FindB.cmake
    # which include FindA.cmake ....
```

Now run *cmake .*

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 4.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Segmentation fault: 11
```

---

Just use guards at beginning of the module (let variable describe path to prevent collision)

*FindB.cmake*

```
if(FIND_B_CMAKE)
  return()
endif()
set(FIND_B_CMAKE 1)

find_package(A)
```

Comment: Currently I don't have any diamond problem; most of the code in my platform files is setting variables etc. But maybe once this will get relevant, so I better include those guards. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Note that CMake 3.10 introduced an [`include_guard`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/include_guard.html#command:include_guard) command to relieve you from having to write your include guards by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use include guards but with some limitations as mentioned [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Performance_Tips#Use_an_include_guard):

> Note that the type of the include guard variable should never be a CACHE variable, since this would cause the variable to persist across multiple CMake configure runs, thereby causing the bug of blocking any subsequent run from reading in the module file's content. A Non-CACHE variable is not fully appropriate either, however, since foreign scopes (which did not adopt that variable definition yet) will lead to (somewhat unnecessary and potentially problematic) re-reading of the file's content. Thus the best choice is implementing this check via a GLOBAL property setting, since such settings have all of the desired characteristics: they're both globally valid and single-session only.
>
> Second, note that only module files that are supportive of such a construct (i.e., files declaring only functions or defining all their settings as CACHE variables) can make use of include guards without issues (Non-CACHE variables, while possibly being referenced within those functions, may suddenly end up being out of scope yet the function will remain reachable).

In my case I have `IncludeGuard.cmake` file with the following content:

```
# Include this file and invoke cmake_include_guard to prevent the CMake script
# parse invoker file multiple times.

macro(cmake_include_guard)
    get_property(INCLUDE_GUARD GLOBAL PROPERTY "INCLUDE_GUARD_${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}")
    if(INCLUDE_GUARD)
        return()
    endif()
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY "INCLUDE_GUARD_${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" TRUE)
endmacro()
```

In common cmake files I use the following snippet at the beggining:

```
include(IncludeGuard)
cmake_include_guard()
```

Macro `cmake_include_guard` use `return()` to stop further content processing.