# How to use floating WindRiver license in cmake

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, wind-river-workbench

I am using WindRiver compiler with floating license on windows Machine.
I have to cross compile a software to ppc architecture using windriver.
I have created a toolchain file with above two.
When i try to generate makefile, it is showing unknown compiler. My doubt is that compiler does not able to find its license.
Is there any way i can solve it?
Do anyone thing the problem may be something different?

The environment variable for license is already set
WRSD_LICENSE_FILE  C:\WindRiver\license

```
#Specify the environment -- embedded
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "ppc")

# specify the cross compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/WindRiver/compilers/diab-5.9.6.4/WIN32/bin/dcc.exe)
```

Comment: "When i try to generate makefile, it is showing unknown compiler" - This just means that CMake is not aware about **kind** of this compiler. See e.g. list compiler identifiers known for CMake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html. It seems you need to have more detailed toolchain for `dcc` compiler. If you know the `dcc` options used for compile and link files, you may try to create that toolchain by yourself. See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372141/how-to-create-cmake-cross-compiling-toolchain-for-vxworks.

Comment: i dont see the CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_ID for wind river compiler. does cmake won't support wind river compiler ?

Answer (score 2):

Now i am able to generate the makefile. The problem here is that i forgot to connect to the license server.
The toolchain setting i have given is

```
#Specify the environment -- embedded
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Generic")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "ppc")
message(STATUS "THE LICENCE FILE IS" $ENV{WRSD_LICENSE_FILE})
# specify the cross compiler
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "C:/WindRiver/compilers/diab-5.9.6.4/WIN32/bin/das.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "C:/WindRiver/compilers/diab-5.9.6.4/WIN32/bin/dcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-tPPC555EH:simple")
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-g")
```